# z-index of dropdown navigation bar behaviour in tailwindcss

Tags: html, css

I am having issue with the z-index of my dropdown navbar. If I set the z-index to negative then the dropdown navbar appears behind the body elements rendering items on the dropdown navbar unclickable. I then tried to keep a positive z index on the dropdown bar and set the main navbar to a higher z-index but it results in abnormal behaviour (the dropdown menu transitions down over the top the main navbar regardless of z-index).

Thanks in advance

```
const Navbar = () => {
const [burger, setBurger] = useState("menu");
const [toggleMenu, setToggleMenu] = useState("");

const menu = function (prev) {
 setBurger(burger === "menu" ? "close" : "menu");
 setToggleMenu(burger === "menu" ? "top-[80px] opacity-80 bg-gray-500" : "");
};

return (
<nav className="p-5 bg-white shadow md:flex md:items-center md:justify-between">
     <div className="flex justify-between items-center z-[100]">
       <span>
         <Image className="mr-4" src="/logo_black.png" alt="logo" width={60} height={60} />
       </span>
       <span className="text-xl font-bold tracking-widest lg:inline hidden">
         COMPANY
       </span>
       <span className="text-3xl cursor-pointer mx-2 md:hidden block">
         <ion-icon name={burger} onClick={menu}></ion-icon>
       </span>
     </div>
     <ul
       className={`md:flex z-[-1] md:bg-white md:z-auto md:items-center md:static absolute w-full left-0 md:w-auto md:py-0 py-4 md:pl-0 pl-7 md:opacity-100 opacity-0 top-[-400px] transition-[top] ease-in duration-500 ${toggleMenu}`}
     >
       <li className="mx-4 my-6 md:my-0">
         <a href="#" className="text-xl hover:text-cyan-500 duration-500">
           About
         </a>
       </li>
       <li className="mx-4 my-6 md:my-0">
         <a href="#" className="text-xl hover:text-cyan-500 duration-500">
           Training
         </a>
       </li>
       <li className="mx-4 my-6 md:my-0">
         <a href="#" className="text-xl hover:text-cyan-500 duration-500">
           Events
         </a>
       </li>
       <li className="mx-4 my-6 md:my-0">
         <a href="#" className="text-xl hover:text-cyan-500 duration-500">
           News
         </a>
       </li>
       <li className="mx-4 my-6 md:my-0">
         <a href="#" className="text-xl hover:text-cyan-500 duration-500">
           Contact
         </a>
       </li>
       <button className="bg-orange-400 rounded text-white duration-500 px-6 py-2 mx-4 hover:bg-orange-200">
         Join Us
       </button>
     </ul>
   </nav>
);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Set a higher z-index for the dropdown menu to ensure it appears above other elements. Currently, it's set to z-[-1] which might cause issues. Change it to a positive value like z-10 or any value higher than the main navbar's z-index.

Modify the transition property to include z-index. This will help transition the z-index smoothly when the dropdown menu opens and closes. Adjust the z-index value in transition as per your needs.

```
className={`md:flex z-10 md:bg-white md:z-auto md:items-center md:static absolute w-full left-0 md:w-auto md:py-0 py-4 md:pl-0 pl-7 md:opacity-100 opacity-0 top-[-400px] transition-[top,z-index] ease-in duration-500 ${toggleMenu}`}
```